# Arduino Mini and USB2Serial not uploading sketch

Tags: usb, programmer, arduino-mini

I am trying to upload my sketch to an Arduino Mini Pro. 
My programmer is the Arduino USB2Serial.
I am running the Windows store app on a Windows 10 machine.

I wired everything up according to the [Arduino Mini guide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoMini).

[image: This is the setup I'm working with right now]

I got different errors just stating something like "error while trying to upload the sketch" before but now I'm always getting this error message after the programmer takes a very long time trying to upload:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

I also didn't forget the capacitor. I added one that is well above the required 100nF and the reset seems to work as the mini came preloaded with the blink example and it briefly stops before the programmer tries to upload. 
I did also try to manually reset at different times before and after klicking the upload button.

I also noticed the programmers RX LED lights up briefly flashing three times shortly after resetting the Arduino but the TX one never lights up.

I also checked if there was an error with the programmer but whenever send something through the serial console while connecting the RX and TX of the programmer it always returns what I typed and both LEDs light up so it should work.

I also manually installed the Arduino USB drivers. The programmer now shows up as "Arduino USB Serial Light Adapter" in the device manager.

I did set the arduino Mini board in the Arduiono IDE settings and also the right port. Though I am not really sure which programmer to choose. I tried pretty much all of them that made sense to me with exactly the same results in every case.

In my memory when playing with these components years ago I thought it was also possible to just connect an Arduino Mini "upside down" like this (I am so sure I remember this working but it won't when trying now):
[image: I know this is not the intended way but it feels so right cause pretty much all the pins line up.]

So right now I don't know what else to try. I even tried multiple different Arduino Minis from different manufacturers and tried resoldering all pins to make sure I didn't mess up.

I also tried pretty much everything from the troubleshooting guide mentioned in the error message. 
Any suggestions what else I could try?

*Update: I now also tried using an old Arduino Uno as programmer like described in the Arduino Mini guide and I tried different versions of the Arduino IDE down to ver 1.0.1 all with the same results.
I even tried installing the drivers from the older versions but Windows 10 wouldn't let me and insisted that the default drivers were suited best. 
I managed installing drivers from the newest Arduino IDE but it didn't change anything.*

*I read [in this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22262/i-cant-get-code-transferred-to-my-arduino-mini-pro?rq=1) That it might be an issue having to do with older Arduino Mini boards (mine are a few years old). But the fixes suggested there did nothing for me. 
The only thing I can think of left to try would be using a machine running an older version of windows in order to be able to use older drivers. But I'm really not sure if it's worth the trouble.*

*I'm also starting to suspect that my programmer might be broken. But then again why did it work looping back serial messages?*

Comment: the USB adapter is not a programmer. the Upload button in IDE does a Serial upload over USB (virtual com port) and doesn't care about Programmer selection it Tools menu. (In Sketch menu there is an option "Upload with programmer" for upload over a programmer connected to the ICSP header)

Comment: the wiring on second picture (reset on adapter to DTR pin on Mini) should work. I don't know if Minis had different bootloaders, but you could try to burn a current bootloader, if you have a ISP programmer or a working Arduino (for Arduino as ISP)

Comment: the Arduino USB to TTL adapter uses FTDI chip which is supported by everything. any OS, any version

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try to burn the bootloader next time